# How to write security rules for just a document

Tags: flutter

I have a collection called users with fields such as email, frame, lname, uid, ts and role

I am trying to write a rule that request only authenticated users to interact with it

Below is the rule I tried

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write : if isSignedIn();
    }
  }
  function isSignedIn(){
     return request.auth.uid != null;
  }
}
```

The problem I have is to understand the path in match. I cannot format it and my simulation is denying me the access
What can I do?
What exactly must be in the users{userId} path?

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me try removing the function like this

```
match /Users/{userId} {
    allow read, write :if request.auth != nul;
}
```

Comment: the {userId} is it a field in ur document?